# Identifying control group ex-post with no baseline- propensity score

Tags: stata, experiment-design, propensity-scores

We are trying to do an individual level impact evaluation using experiments. The intervention who's impact we are studying was at the town level.
Unfortunately, we do not have a baseline control group (town or individual). To identify a control group we are conducting a PSM at the town level to identify a control group of towns using nearest neighbor matching. Once we have pairs of control-treatment towns, we will randomly select pairs to conduct the individual-level experiment in.

This is a simplified version of the code we are using to identify the pairs.

```
pscore treated $pscore_controls, 
pscore (mypscore) comsup numblo(5) level(0.01) blockid(myblockid)

psmatch2 treated, pscore( mypscore ) caliper (.001) noreplace neighbor(1) 
**//nearest neighbor matching//**

gen pair = _id if _treated==0
replace pair = _n1 if _treated==1 
**//identifies the matched treated   
neighbor //**
bysort pair: egen paircount =count(pair)
tab paircount **//drop if !=2, if not 2 means no nearest neighbor was found in given caliper width- 119 of 157 treated towns matched//**
```

I have two questions:

1. Given that the intervention was at the village level but our outcome of interest is at the individual level- is the above-mentioned method a sound way to identify a control group?
2. The matching controls we are using are for 2010, the intervention was in 2015, the experiment will be in 2017/2018. We are assuming that since 2010 levels are informing our matching, they are pre-intervention and hence a sound way to identify a control group. Is there another way to identify a sound-control group?

Also posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1414208-identifying-control-group-ex-post-with-no-baseline-propensity-score

Comment: I am a bit confused. Will you have individual-level data from untreated towns? Or any untreated data from treated towns?

Comment: We will have individual-level data from both treated and untreated towns..but all this data will be post-intervention data. We have no baseline individual-level data.